# Use GET in require

Tags: php

I have 2 simple PHP files:

test.php

```
<?php
$a=10;
require "use.php?c=$a";
?>
```

use.php:

```
<?php
$test=$_GET['c'];
echo $test;
?>
```

But it returns nothing.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include()` and `require()` do not make HTTP requests unless you supply a full URL, they work on the local file system. `$_GET` and friends use URL parameters when they are populated. You code should not work, because you are trying to `require()` a file called `use.php?c=$a`, not a file called `use.php` passing the value `$a` to the parameter `c`, which is what you want.

This will work:

**test.php**

```
<?php
$a=10;
require "use.php";
?>
```

**use.php**

```
<?php
echo $a;
?>
```

If you are getting no output, you should enable error reporting:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not the way you want to use `require`: You usually use it for including a *filesystem* path, which doesn't work with GET parameters. GET parameters work only in HTTP URLs. (HTTP requests are slow, hence you almost never want to include somthing through a URL.)

The code that is `require`d gets executed as if it were part of the current script.

So you could do:

```
<?php
$a=10;
require "use.php";
?>
```

use.php

```
<?php
$test=$a;
echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: I see.  But then I would have to keep variable names between files.  Is there a way that does not need variable names to be the same?

Comment: @David what is it you want to do in the first place? Maybe if you elaborate, somebody can come up with a good suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Require? Maybe Location what you are looking for:

```
$a=10;
header( "Location: use.php?c=$a" ) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try following code:

```
$oldget = $_GET;
$_GET = array('c'=>'a');
require "use.php";
$_GET = $oldget;
```

But I think, you should change your architecture